# Android - Firebase realtime database reference pointing to invalid url

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android Java.

When trying to reference my Realtime Database I'm using this to get the reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase rootDatabase;
DatabaseReference rootReference;

rootDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Log.i("rootDatabase", String.valueOf(rootDatabase));

rootReference = rootDatabase.getReference("users");
Log.i("rootReference", String.valueOf(rootReference));
```

The URL shown in the console is different from that associated with my firebase project:
Output in the console

```
I/rootDatabase: com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase@<ProjectID>
I/rootReference: https://<Project-Name>-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users
```

When I open the URL from the console I get a page saying "not found".

But the URL that is shown above the database in the firebase console and in the google-services.json under firebase_url is:

```
https://<Project-Name>-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/
```

Is there any way that I can either change the location of the Firebase database to no be in the Europe-west region or change some way to get the reference to the new server region? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
Log.i("rootDatabase", String.valueOf(rootDatabase));
```

You are passing to the valueOf() method the `rootDatabase` object, which is of type FirebaseDatabase. So you are only printing the String representation of the object, which is actually a memory address. However, when you are using this line:

```
Log.i("rootReference", String.valueOf(rootReference));
```

You are passing a different object to the valueOf() method. This time the object is of type DatabaseReference. Now the String representation of the object is actually a URL that points to your project.

> Is there any way that I can either change the location of the firebase database to no be in the Europe-west region

Once you set the location, this cannot be changed. If you need another location, you need to create another project, set the location to be in another region than the Europe-west region, download the JSON file again and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, my issue is the URL I get from ```Log.i("rootReference", String.valueOf(rootReference));``` is different to the one that is associated with the URL on my console page.

Comment: My apologies after further research a rebuild of my project to get the new google-services.json to be recognised was all that was required. Thank you for your help.